# SAS - PROC SURVEYSELECT with dynamic sample size using a table reference each sample size

Tags: sas

I'm having trouble using PROC SURVEYSELECT where I need to reference a table (example below) and choose the corresponding sample size for each ID (strata).

Would this be done with a macro?  If so, how do I code this so that it would go through each row of the table, select the ID and sample size and loop the surveyselect for each strata?  I'd really not like to hard code each ID and sample size, as I've seen that is an option, bc this list would be constantly changing.

I haven't had much experience with macros, so not sure if this is the correct path or if this can be done another way.  Looking for any help/guidance/suggestions.

| ID | Sample Size |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 15 |
| 456 | 25 |
| 789 | 75 |
| 999 | 80 |

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use loops, you can just use call execute statement.

```
data have;
    input ID Sample_size;
    datalines;
123 15
456 25
789 75
999 80
;
run;
```

Since you didn't give any details about how your proc surveyselect look like, I left your macro empty - you just have to fill in the blancs (your data sets and surveyselect procedure options).

```
%macro Survey_select(ID, Sample_size);
    proc surveyselect <your info>;
        <your info>;
    run;
%mend Survey_select;
```

Call execute will generate code needed to run your macro for every member in your list.

```
data _null_;
    set have;
    call execute(cats('%Survey_select(',ID,',',Sample_size,')'));
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In the first part of the code with datalines, instead of typing them in manually by ID/Sample Size, is there a way to reference the table instead?  That's would I'm considering as the dynamic sample size.  Does that make sense, or at all possible?

Comment: That IS a reference table... You can create it manually like I did, or you can reference an already existing one, or create one from your other tables.

Comment: How would I reference the table?   Would "input" be the name of the ref table?  Then I don't need to input the ID and size?  Do I still need "datalines"?

Comment: In mine example this reference table is named have. And you have to somehow put your data into the table, using datalines is just one way. I suggest you go trough some SAS documentation and basic exercises to familiarise yourself with SAS syntax.